# Find out date difference JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

How to find out date difference between check-in and check-out date.

```
function Checkdate(id)
{
  var txtCheckinNew = $(id).parents("table").find("#[id$=TransferDate]").val(); //04/30/2013
  var txtCheckoutNew =$(id).parents("table").find("#[id$=TransferDate1]").val(); //05/03/2013
  var diff =   Date(txtCheckoutNew) - Date(txtCheckinNew);
  alert(diff);      
}
```

Comment: What format is the input data? And what should be the output?

Comment: check in :- 04/30/2013 and check out :- 5/03/2013

Comment: `var diff =  new Date(txtCheckoutNew) - new Date(txtCheckinNew);` ?

Comment: @Jashwant trying to find out date difference

Comment: Yes, have you tried my code ?

Comment: @Jashwant i try...it reply.. 259200000

Comment: 259200000 is the date difference in milliseconds.

Comment: @HarshitTailor, 259200000 is the date differenc in ms. You can convert it to suit your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `Date.parse`

```
var txtCheckinNew = Date.parse($('#TransferDate').val());
var txtCheckoutNew = Date.parse($('#TransferDate1').val());
alert((txtCheckoutNew-txtCheckinNew)/(24*60*60*1000));
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8vB2v/)

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look on 
http://jsfiddle.net/2dJAN/1/

```
<div class="date"></div>

var Date1 = new Date (2008, 7, 25);
var Date2 = new Date (2008, 7, 27);
var one_day = 1000*60*60*24;
var Days = (Date2.getTime() - Date1.getTime())/(one_day)
$('.date').html(Days)
```